# Calculating amount of subgroups and normal groups of $G$ for $[G:Z(G)] = 6$ containing $Z(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group for which $[G: Z(G)] = 6$. How many subgroups and normal groups does $G$ have that contain $Z(G)$.

---

I am trying to solve this problem, I had the following ideas:

- Using the Class equation $|G| = |Z(G)| + \sum_{i=m+1}^n |Cl(a_i)|$: I first thought that I could use this equation, but the condition that $Z(G)$ has to be contained in the subgroups, leads me to think that I can't use the class equation.
- $|G| = |C_G(x)|*|Cl(x)|$. Since $Z(G) = \cap_{x \in G} C_G(x)$ I thought  I could maybe use this to calculate the amount of subgroups or normal groups, but I don't really know how to continue this idea.

I think my second idea is maybe in the right direction but I don't know how to go further nor do I know if it's actually the right idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint 1: There exists no group $\;G\;$ such that $\;G/Z(G)\;$ is non-trivial cyclic.

Hint 2: There exist only two groups of order $\;6\;$: an abelian (cyclic, in fact) one, and a non abelian one isomorphic with $\;S_3\;$ .

Comment: That leads to the fact that $G/Z(G)$ is isomorphic to $S_3$

Comment: Is this reasoning correct:
Hint 1: If $G$ were a group s.t. $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is commutative and $G = Z(G)$, which contradicts $[G:Z(G)]=6$.
Hint 2: Since we know there are only 2 groups of order 6, since $G/Z(G)$ is not cyclic, it follows that it is not abelian (since it would be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_6$ which is cyclic). So $G/Z(G) \cong S_3$.
I know that $S_3$ has 6 subgroups, each containing Id, (which is mapped onto $Z(G)$). Is it true that G has 6 subgroups which contain $Z(G)$ of which 4 are normal subgroups, isomorphic to (Id, {Id, (12)}, {Id, (13)}, {Id, (23)})?

Comment: That would be 6 subgroups including $Z(G)$ and $G$.

Comment: @fieke_2000 It's almost right...but $\;S_3\;$ has only one non-trivial *proper*  normal subgroup: the one of order three. The three proper subgroups of order two are **not** normal...

Comment: Oh right! I was confused, the non-trivial normal subgroup would be the subgroup of even permutations, $A_3 = ${$Id, (123),(132)$}. Thank you for your answer!